# Summarize data oer country

Tags: tableau-api

I am on Tableau and I try to do something similar to the SELECT DISTINCT query in SQL and run calcculations on the distinct data.

I have data on startups in different countries. I would like to create and aggregate for the country to run mean, median, etc ...

How would you do this calculation in Tableau ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you post a screenshot of Dimensions and Measures then it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In Tableau Count Distinct is using the function COUNTD(), Mean is equivalent to AVG() and Median to Median()